# How to know file type of some file uploaded in a form with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I would like to know the type of file obtained with req.files in NodeJS. I need this because the file uploaded has to be a photo for the well work of the app. It not only helps me to check that it is not a .jpg since you can make a .txt and change the extension.

The form is the following:

```
form(class="form add-form space-down" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
                div.title
                    h1 UPLOAD NEW PROGRESS 
                    div.form-group
                        label(for="weight") Weight: 
                        input(type="number" name="weight" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your weight")
                    div.form-group
                        label(for="front") Upload a front photo 
                        input(type="file" name="front" accept="image/*")
                    div.form-group
                        label(for="from_side") Upload a from side photo 
                        input(type="file" name="from_side" accept="image/*")
                    div.form-group
                        label(for="backwards") Upload a backwards photo 
                        input(type="file" name="backwards" accept="image/*")
```

And the router handle is the following to obtain the photos uploaded:

```
routerProgress.post("/home/upload-progress", (req, res) => {
    const front = req.files.front;
    const from_side = req.files.from_side;
    const backwards = req.files.backwards;
}
```

How can I be sure that front, from_side and backwards are photos?

If anyone has any idea how to do it, I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Create a function which returns the extension of the file and you can check if it is a valid image extension or not.

```
routerProgress.post("/home/upload-progress", (req, res) => {
  
    const front = getFileExtension(req.files.front);
    const from_side = getFileExtension(req.files.from_side);
    const backwards = getFileExtension(req.files.backwards);
    
    if (front) {
        // its an image, do something
    }

}

function getFileExtension (filename) {
     const allowedFileExt = ['JPEG', 'JPG', 'PNG', 'GIF', 'TIFF', 'PSD', 'PDF']; // you can add as per your requirement
     const fileExt = /[^.]+$/.exec(filename);
     return allowedFileExt.includes(fileExt[0].toUpperCase());
}
```

If that is the case, you should use [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic), it checks the content of the file instead checking only the extension. Try using this lib it will be more useful for your use case. Also, take a look at this npm package [image-type](https://github.com/sindresorhus/image-type)

Comment: this won't work, someone can have a .txt file and change it for .jpg, it will pass the check but it isn't a photo.

Comment: @Gonsa02 I have updated the answer with more concrete info.